# Delete empty rows in spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, delete-row, vmerge

I am using VMerge script to merge the data in two sheets of a Google spreadsheet to another sheet. The sample [Spreadsheet is here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AozvCNI02VmpdG9MNkhIWk8xVWJ0XzVsLVN0aHdVUlE&usp=sharing). The merged data is in the sheet named **`merge`**. Now how can I remove the blank rows in the merged data. The blank rows comes from the `Sheet1` & `Sheet2`. I have given the full range `A1:B` in the formula

```
=VMERGE(ImportRange("0AozvCNI02VmpdG9MNkhIWk8xVWJ0XzVsLVN0aHdVUlE","Sheet1!A1:B");ImportRange("0AozvCNI02VmpdG9MNkhIWk8xVWJ0XzVsLVN0aHdVUlE","Sheet2!A2:B"))
```

Because extra data is added to sheet1 & sheet2 occasionally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is solved using the query as,

```
=Query(VMERGE((ImportRange("0AozvCNI02VmpdG9MNkhIWk8xVWJ0XzVsLVN0aHdVUlE","Sheet1!A1:B"));ImportRange("0AozvCNI02VmpdG9MNkhIWk8xVWJ0XzVsLVN0aHdVUlE","Sheet2!A2:B")); "select * where Col1 is not null")
```

See the [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AozvCNI02VmpdG9MNkhIWk8xVWJ0XzVsLVN0aHdVUlE#gid=4) here for reference.